# report for range to numbers in shell

Tags: bash, shell

i would like to have a report showing range of salary. i've tried the code below but it keeps counting all the data in the text file without searching for the range first
please advise what can be improved.

txt

```
3,Frank,CFO,91111453,Salaried,2333
1,Mary,CEO,93424222,Salaried,1111
5,John,Sales user,9321312,Commission,9999
7,Chris,Admin,98888753,Hourly,122
```

result [WHAT I WANT AS OUTPUT]

```
Range       total number
1-1000      1
1001-2000   2
```

code:

```
  echo "range       Total"
   awk '{t==$6}END{ if (t < 1001) count++ } END { print "$0 - 999\t\t"count }' $file
   awk '{t==$6}END{ if (1001<$6<2000) count++ } END { print "$1000 - 2999\t\t"count }' $file
```

Comment: Please be more explicit about what you want to achieve.

Comment: iwant to achieve the RESULT .. as the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this awk program

```
BEGIN {
    FS=","
    OFS="\t"
    print "Range    ", "total number"
}
{
    ranges[int($6 / 1000)*1000]++
}
END {
    for (r in ranges)
        print r "-" (r+999) ":", ranges[r]
}
```

Comment: You can also print the header line in the `BEGIN` block.

Comment: @Alien: Stuff this in a file called `test.awk` and call it like `awk -f test.awk < YOURDATAFILE`

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read LINE
do
    LINE=${LINE##*,}
    [[ ${LINE} -ge 1    ]] && [[ ${LINE} -le 1000 ]] && (( ++RANGE1 ))
    [[ ${LINE} -ge 1001 ]] && [[ ${LINE} -le 2000 ]] && (( ++RANGE2 ))
done < "/path/to/report"

echo "
Range        total number
1 - 1000     ${RANGE1}
1001 - 2000  ${RANGE2}
"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to have an arbitrary number of ranges instead of just two (pure bash):

```
#!/bin/bash

#calculating
while read LINE
do
    LINE=${LINE##*,} ; (( ++RANGE[LINE /= 1000] ))
done < "/your/file/here"

#printing
echo -e "Range\t\ttotal number"
for NR in {0..10}
do
    echo -e "${NR}001 - $(( $NR + 1 ))000\t${RANGE[$NR]}"
done
```